# continuing from cell swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I'm currently having trouble continuing from a cell in another function, below are my codes. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
private func datePickerCell(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, property: Property, with value: String, with name: String, changeHandler: @escaping((String) -> Bool)) -> FUISimplePropertyFormCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FUISimplePropertyFormCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FUISimplePropertyFormCell

    // toolbar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    // bar button item
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed)) //<-- calls the outside function
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    cell.valueTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

    //assigning date picker to text field
    cell.valueTextField.inputView = datePicker

    cell.isEditable = true
    cell.keyName = name
    cell.value = value

    return cell


}

func donePressed(){ //<-- function that gets called by the done button
    cell.valueTextField.text = "\(datePicker.date)" // <-- ERROR
    // i'd like to continue editing the cell here

}
```

Comment: continue  editing in the sense do you mean you want to add something more to the same cell ? If so from what I understand from your question you can maybe use a conditional statement which keeps a check if the cell has data in it then Dont invoke the datepicker instead append to the cell. What It means is If data exists within cell{  Dont invoke datepicker, and make cell editable } This is something i'm telling from what I understand from your question. Clarify if I am right maybe I can help

Comment: Yes you're exactly right, i'd like to change the value of cell.valueTextField.text to the current date picked when the user clicks on the done button in the datepicker

Comment: oooh you meant that wait i'll provide you with the code

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me explain with my code itself. This is a reminder screen I made for our app. So in this screen I have a portion of code for setting the timepicker to an input field. In your case its going to be the Cell.

So this is how you do it. Check the view did load function below:
The code below will have to be changed to your field name and the date formatter is to format the style in which you want to display it.

Let me know if u need any help on this.

```
 timeInput.layer.addSublayer(bottomLineTimePicker)
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            // This is the code you need //
            timeInput.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker.date)
```

This is the full Code.

```
import UIKit

class Reminder: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timePickerStack: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var setReminderSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var setReminderButton: UIButton!

    let timePicker = UIDatePicker()
    let bottomLineTimePicker = CALayer()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    @IBAction func setReminder(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let nextDate = NotificationManager.shared.schedule(time: self.timePicker.date, repeats: true)

        if nextDate != nil {

            print("\(nextDate!.timeIntervalSinceNow.formattedTime)")

        }
        setReminderStatus(reminderStatus: true,reminderTime:self.timePicker.date)

    }

    func createTimePicker(){

        timePicker.datePickerMode = .time

        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)

        timeInput.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        timeInput.inputView = timePicker

    }

    func donePressed(){

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        timeInput.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func reminderSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if(sender.isOn == true){
            timePickerStack.isHidden = false
        }else{
            NotificationManager.shared.cancelAllNotifications()
            timePickerStack.isHidden = true
            unsetReminder()
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if(issetReminder()){
            setReminderSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
            timePickerStack.isHidden = false
        }else{
            setReminderSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
            timePickerStack.isHidden = true
        }

        createTimePicker()

        bottomLineTimePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: timeInput.frame.height - 1, width: timeInput.frame.width, height: 1.0)
        bottomLineTimePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 23/255.5, green: 155/255.5, blue: 167/255.5, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

        timeInput.layer.addSublayer(bottomLineTimePicker)
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        // This is the code you need //
        timeInput.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker.date)

        setReminderButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let backButtonPressed = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navController") as! IndexNavController
        self.present(backButtonPressed, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

extension TimeInterval{
    var formattedTime:String{

        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .brief
        formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = false
        formatter.includesTimeRemainingPhrase = false
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.calendar = Calendar.current

        return formatter.string(from: self) ?? ""

    }
}
```